# What MySQL datatype would store this Java BigInteger?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, biginteger

I'm using Java 6, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, and Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  I have a String (maximum of 32 characters) that I wish to convert to a number and then back again to a String.  I want to know what MySQL (v 5.5) data type I should use to store the number (which I think is a BigInteger) and I would also like to know if there's a better way to do the conversion.  Right now, I'm doing

```
// Convert to integer
final BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(myString.getBytes());

// Convert back to a string
final String oldString = new String(bigInt.toByteArray());
```

The Hibernate mapping on the field in question is

```
@Column(name = "ORDER_ID")
private BigInteger orderId;
```

Thanks for your help, -

Comment: Could you specify the format of the String?  Is it a numeric string, e.g. "12345", or a sequence of byte integers?

Comment: The string may contain numbers, but not necessarily.  It will be a GUID -- so a 32 character sequence in which each character is either a number of a letter from "A" to "F".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the NUMERIC datatype.  I've used that to store very large decimal numbers up to 39 digits long.

The database field has a type of "NUMERIC(39)".

The hibernate mapping used was:

```
<property name="foo" type="big_integer" column="ORDER_ID" length="39"/>
```

To convert a string to a BigInteger from a hex string, use:

```
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(myString, 16);
```

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work.  Got error "org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'ORDER_ID' at row 1"

Comment: Updated my answer with hibernate and mysql particulars.  What mapping and column types did you try it with?

Comment: I found that NUMERIC(50) took care of things (I was still getting some errors the other way).  Added the Hibernate mapping for posterity.